# Parse Django Models Server Side or Client Side?

Tags: javascript, python, django

While working on django app development what is the best practice for displaying model objects on the client side? Should the models be parsed using the server side code or best left to client side templating language/javascript?

For Example on the server side:

```
for order in to_do_orders:
        orderDict[order.orderID] = Order.objects.get(pk=order.orderID.id)
        orderDict['customer'] = Customer.objects.get(pk=Order.objects.get(pk=order.orderID.id).customer.id)
```

vs client:

```
{% for order in orders %}
        {{ order.id }}</a></li>
        {{customer}}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: these are both on the server side. there is no javascript happening here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Django, my understanding is this:

If a routine affects how the data is displayed, put the logic in the template.

If a routine affects which data is displayed, put the logic in a function in the view.

If a routine affects how the data is retrieved, consider using a model manager instead of a view function.

In your example, using `order.id` in the template is handy, since you only needed to pass a container object to the template - the dictionary of orders.

Answer (score -1):

What you call "Server" vs "client" is actually Python code vs Templates, which are both interpreted on the server.

I do not think it makes a difference, except that readability and re-usability are keys. For this goal, the second option (Using Template functions) certainly looks the best. Although I'm quite sure that there are a lot of exceptions.

Comment: This is neither PHP nor Twig <g>